# jQTouch Spinning Wheel (Cubiq) Implementation Won't Work

Tags: jquery, iphone, jqtouch, iphone-web-app

I am trying to get a nice [Spinning Wheel working within my webapp](http://www.ecbonline.com/process/iphone/spinning.php).

However, I keep receiving an error within Mobile Safari that the variable 'blabla' cannot be found.

I have implemented both of these suggested solutions:

1. Change SpinningWheelCSS
2. Change JQTouch CSS, JS files, and add JQTouch wrapper to body

Neither worked for me.

I am trying to use the incredible Spinning Wheel by Cubiq.org.

I'm likely doing something wrong, but for the life of me I can't figure out what it is. Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I tried placing all the code from the Spinning page into the Index.html page, so all the HTML code for all pages were on there. That still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the very latest version of JQTouch from the trunk at Google Code:
http://code.google.com/p/jqtouch/source/checkout

This fixed the problem, as the the latest version has included a namespace in the JQTouch.css stylesheet, which resolves the conflicts with the Spinning Wheel plugin.

Hopefully this helps someone else who is experiencing the same problem.

Comment: This helped me. Thanks.
By the way, you should have accepted your own answer :)

Comment: hi @Peter. I just came across this question. I'm trying to implement the spinwheel together with jQTouch. However, I'm using jQTouch Beta 3 already but there seems to be a problem. I too suspect that there is a conflict between jQTouch and Spin Wheel. May I ask how do you determine if the JQTouch.css has included a namespace?

Answer (score 1):

I am using the spinning wheel in my web app and I removed the cancel/done buttons since I call a new #id for it, you just need to edit the js and css coming along with the spinningwheel. 
However, no previous/next buttons are visible there, do you mean the cancel/done ones?

I call the wheel on a page where I also have a radio group and it won't function when the wheel's there - do you have a clue what I'm doing wrong? I also have a picture on that screen, if the user clicks it, it should change. As long as the wheel does not appear, it all goes well...

Answer (score 0):

Your href where you call the class should direct to a #htmlid tag on the same page